# Getting UIView from UIPickerView with images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uipickerview

I have a UIPicker view containing 4 columns with the same array of 6 images in each column (colors). I have a button which, when pressed, will display the 4 images on the UIPickerView in separate views. Problem is, I can't seem to find a way to get the UIView from a UIPickerView.

Here is a picture of what the finished app will look like:
[image]

As you can see, the user will set the 4 columns to some colors and when they press the Guess button, it should display the 4 guesses in the space below (either in ImageViews or in a canvas).

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the view for a particular view by calling `viewForRow:forComponent:` method.

```
UIView * selectedViewInFirstComponent = [pickerView viewForRow:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] forComponent:0];
```

and so on for the other components.

The problem here is that you can't add it to another view as subview as there can be only one superview for any view. You should rather get the color which you might be using as the data source.

```
UIColor * colorForFirstComponent = [colors objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];

// Now use this color to fill one of the views in the guess block.
```